# Function that search for one character, then count how many times it appears Python

Tags: python, string, input, count, character

I'm new to python and I'm looking to make a program that asks a user to fill in a string of characters (a phrase or other) and then fill in a specific character.

The program must **return the number of occurrences of the character in the string**. I need to use the **.count** function but I can't get my code to work.

Any help will be welcome!

```
def search(text,character):
    '''This function searches for one character, defined as 2nd argument, 
    in a given text / string of characters, defined as 1 st argument, 
    and counts how many times it appears'''
    
    #The 1st argument text here represents the input in which you are looking for
    text = input("Type here the text you want: ")
    
    #The 2nd argument character represents the character you are looking for
    character = input("Type the character you want to count: ")
        
    
    
    text.count('character')
    print text.count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the code you want,
I created a function search which takes two parameters :

- *text* the string I search in
- *character* the string I want to count

I then store the number of occurences of the character in the string text and print it

```py
def search(text,character):
    '''This function searches for one character, defined as 2nd argument, 
    in a given text / string of characters, defined as 1 st argument, 
    and counts how many times it appears'''
    
    occ = text.count(character)
    print("Occurences:",occ)

#The 1st argument text here represents the input in which you are looking for
text = input("Type here the text you want: ")

#The 2nd argument character represents the character you are looking for
character = input("Type the character you want to count: ")
search(text,character)
```

Comment: Original function requires you to just return it though, not print it. Printing it in the function would be a bad habit due to the reusabiity reasons I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In you code you should save text.count(character) in a variable and then print the variable. You do not see anything because you don't print the right thing.
Also you should put the variable character inside count and not a string 'character'

```
var = text.count(character)
print var
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your specifications, the function only returns the value, doesn't print it. And as a best practice, functions should do only 1 thing. That will improve their reusability. If you were to print the occurrances inside the function too, that would limit where else you can use that function.

Here I input a string and a character, then I found out how many times the character occurs inside the string using my function:

```
def search(text, character):
count = 0

# for every c (stands for character) in text    
for c in text:
    if c == character:
        count += 1
        
return count

txt = input('Enter text: ')
ch  = input('Enter character: ')

print('Number of occurrances: ', search(txt, ch))
```

Note that you could also save `search(txt, ch)` in a variable such as `cnt = search(txt, ch)` and use it later. You could print using your variable too, such as `print('Number of occurrances: ', cnt)`.

Comment: I think a simpler way would be: sum([c==character for c in text])

Comment: That adds one more concept therefore more complexity to the program. I don't think a beginner needs that at the moment. Beginners should deal with one thing at a time. There are a ton of ways to do it yet this is probably one of the most explicit and understandable one.